# Need help from laravel / query builder masters! trying to filter complicated relationship :(

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

### Table Relationships

**orders** <-- Has many --> **orderdaytimes**
**orderdaytimes** <--belongsToMany--> **stores** (pivot table name: order_day_time_stores)

### Given values & keys

1. *Orders:* contains a field called "**supplier_id**"
2. *Orderdaytimes:* contains a field "**date**"
3. *order_day_time_stores*: the pivot table, contains "**user_id**" and "**store_id**"

### Question

Given "**supplier_id", "date**" and "**store_id**", I want to find out which records in the "order_day_time_stores" pivot table meets these criteria.

Can someone give me an idea of how I should go about constructing the query?

Thanks heeeeap :3

Comment: format your post, if you want a good answer :)

Comment: hope it looks better T.T

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Could you provide us with queries that you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

Your question could be better. You may want to post your complete Models and / or migrations.

Based on what I understood, this may be what you are looking for:

Assuming you have the models Store, OrderDayTime and Order.
In the Store model, let's assume that your relationship with OrderDayTime is named order_day_times.
Also, in the OrderDayTime model, the relationship with Order is named orders.

```
$result = Store::find(store_id)
                 ->order_day_times->where('date', date)
                 ->whereHas('orders', function ($q) use (supplier_id) {
                     $q->where('supplier_id', supplier_id);
                 })->with('orders')
                 ->get();
```